# How to simulate a click on LinkButton when <a> is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

How can I simulate a click on the LinkButton so that CodeBehind will be read once an href is being clicked?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Home" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="LinkButton_Home_Click">Home</asp:LinkButton></li>

<a href="#">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger `click` event using `jquery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
         $('#'+'<%=LinkButton_Home.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

*Dont forgot to include reqired jquery library.*

Comment: Thanks!. If I need to do this multiple times with different linkbutton, will id be better?